# Always able to read .eps files, now can't open/convert this specific one

Tags: command-line, gimp, convert

I am trying to open an `.eps` file, but I can't: every reader I try just freezes, even though the same opened other `.eps` files previously. I tried with `gimp`, which usually opens whatever files, but it returns the error:

```
Opening "file.eps" has failed: impossible to open postscript file "file.eps"
```

Then I tried to `convert` the file to a `.png`, with the hope to open it. But the `convert` command also gives error:

```
$ convert file.eps file.png
convert: not authorized `file.eps' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
convert: no images defined `file.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.
```

I [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453) that modifying the `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` file, may be the way to go, but I am not sure that is the proper way for my case.

EDIT: The file is attached to an email and I can download it and open it from another machine with Photoshop, and on my mobile with an EPS Viewer app. The file is ok, not corrupted.

Comment: Is there any application that can open the file? The file could be corrupt.

Comment: Inkscape can also open these if your file isn't corrupted, might be worth trying if you have it installed?

Comment: @xenoid, sorry I haven't said that before. The file is not corrupted. I have edited the original thread.

Comment: You are only stating that the file isn't corrupted on the other machines. Maybe the copy you use on the target machine is corrupt, or the remote access is corrupting the file. The only way to know is to make a hash (MD5 or else) on the various systems and compare them.

Comment: @xenoid, edited again: the file is attached to an email. I don't need to transfer it or copy/paste it.

Comment: Your email client could be corrupting it. Comparing checksum across systems is the only way to rule out this possibility.

Comment: @xenoid, thanks. i download the attachment from the same client on my machine or on my mobile phone. Ho can I checksum the file on my phone? I do not have another machine at the moment. If I download the attachment on my machine, and then send it by email to a friend, he is able to open it with photoshop. Does this still not rule out the corruption possibility?

Comment: No, this indeed rules out the corruption, if you indeed saved it to disk and re-attached to a new mail.

Answer (score 1):

on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS it was enought to comment/remove the lines in `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` marked below. That is right after the `<!-- disable ghostscript format type -->` remove those lines.

```
<policymap>
   ...
  <!-- disable ghostscript format types -->
  <!-- comment or remove the lines below
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="EPS" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />
  <policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="XPS" />
  -->
</policymap>
```

As the answer you linked in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution isn't to revert the change to ImageMagick.

That was kept after the bug in Ghostscript's sandbox was fixed as "Why are we letting arbitrary web applications run a Turing-complete programming language like Postscript in a sandbox when they get lazy about verifying the uploaded file really *is* the format the extension says?"

Instead, just go straight to the Ghostscript command specified in the ImageMagick `delegates.xml` config file when you knowingly want to render Postscript.

Here's a cleaned-up version of the kind of EPS-to-PNG command you want:

```
gs -dSAFER -dEPSCrop -r600 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -o file.png file.eps
```

- `-dSAFER` is something you *always* want. Without it, Ghostscript doesn't even *try* to sandbox the Postscript and it's only off by default for legacy compatibility reasons.
- `-dEPSCrop` is optional. It tells Ghostscript to crop the output to the actual content, rather than rendering the entire page specified by the input file.
- `-r600` specifies the DPI and, thus, the output size. (Inches specified by the EPS file multiplied by the Dots Per Inch equals pixel dimensions. The default is usually 72 dpi.)
- `-sDEVICE=pngalpha` specifies the output format. It's called `-sDEVICE` because writing to a file is like a "Print to PDF" driver. There are [multiple](https://ghostscript.com/doc/Devices.htm) such output drivers to choose from.
- `-o file.png` is shorthand for `-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=file.png` which should be fairly self-explanatory.